# How can i Implement iterator insert (const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last) of vector in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

Hello I am trying to make vector class in C++. and I want to make below one. Can you hint me how to make?
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/
std::vector::insert
range (3)
template 
iterator insert (const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);

Here is my code. and plz let me know if there are mistakes.

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "dsexceptions.h"

template <typename Object>
class Vector
{
public:
    explicit Vector(int initSize = 0)
        : theSize(initSize), theCapacity(initSize + SPARE_CAPACITY),objects(nullptr)
        
    {
        (objects = new Object[theCapacity]);
        for(int k=0; k<theSize; ++k)
        {
            objects[k] = 0;
        }
    }
    Vector(const Vector& rhs)
        : theSize(rhs.theSize), theCapacity( rhs.theCapacity ), objects( nullptr)
    {
        objects = new Object[theCapacity];
        for (int k = 0; k < theSize; ++k)
            objects[k] = rhs.objects[k];
    }

    Vector& operator= (const Vector& rhs)
    {
        Vector copy = rhs;
        std::swap(*this, copy);
        return *this;
    }

    ~Vector()
    {
        delete[] objects;
    }

    Vector(Vector&& rhs)
        : theSize{ rhs.theSize }, theCapacity{ rhs.theCapacity }, objects{ rhs.objects }
    {
        rhs.objects = nullptr;
        rhs.theSize = 0;
        rhs.theCapacity = 0;
    }

    Vector& operator= (Vector&& rhs)
    {
        std::swap(theSize, rhs.theSize);
        std::swap(theCapacity, rhs.theCapacity);
        std::swap(objects, rhs.objects);

        return *this;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return size() == 0;
    }
    int size() const
    {
        return theSize;
    }
    int capacity() const
    {
        return theCapacity;
    }

    Object& operator[](int index)
    {
#ifndef NO_CHECK
        if (index < 0 || index >= size())
            throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{ };
#endif
        return objects[index];
    }

    const Object& operator[](int index) const
    {
#ifndef NO_CHECK
        if (index < 0 || index >= size())
            throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{ };
#endif
        return objects[index];
    }

    void resize(int newSize)
    {
        if (newSize > theCapacity)
            reserve(newSize * 2);
        theSize = newSize;
    }

    void reserve(int newCapacity)
    {
        if (newCapacity < theSize)
            return;

        Object* newArray = new Object[newCapacity];
        for (int k = 0; k < theSize; ++k)
            newArray[k] = std::move(objects[k]);

        theCapacity = newCapacity;
        std::swap(objects, newArray);
        delete[] newArray;
    }

    // Stacky stuff
    void push_back(const Object& x)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        objects[theSize++] = x;
    }
    // Stacky stuff
    void push_back(Object&& x)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        objects[theSize++] = std::move(x);
    }

    void pop_back()
    {
        if (empty())
            throw UnderflowException{ };
        --theSize;
    }

    const Object& back() const
    {
        if (empty())
            throw UnderflowException{ };
        return objects[theSize - 1];
    }

    // Iterator stuff: not bounds checked
    typedef Object* iterator;
    typedef const Object* const_iterator;

    iterator begin()
    {
        return &objects[0];
    }
    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return &objects[0];
    }
    iterator end()
    {
        return &objects[size()];
    }
    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return &objects[size()];
    }

    static const int SPARE_CAPACITY = 2;

    /*************************************************************************/
    /*************************************************************************/
 
    iterator insert(const_iterator position, const Object& val)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
        {
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        }
        int index = position - objects;
        for (int i = theSize - 1; i >= index; --i)
            objects[i + 1] = objects[i];
        objects[index] = val;
        theSize++;

        return &objects;
        
    }

    iterator insert(const_iterator position, Object&& val)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
        {
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        }
        int index = position - objects;
        for (int i = theSize-1; i>=index; --i)
            objects[i+1] = objects[i];
        objects[index] = std::move(val);
        theSize++;

        return objects;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre].

Comment: `(first - last)` is either 0, a meaningless number, or is ill-formed. did you mean `std::distance(first, last)`?

Comment: @Caleth To be exact, I was curious about the meaning of the 'first' and 'last' parameters.

Comment: Which part of the explanation you linked to don't you understand?

Comment: @molbdnilo the 3rd one(range (3) 
template <class InputIterator>
iterator insert (const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last)); and I think i can understand how i use, but I dont know how to make. and the reason I cannot make it properly is I think i can't understand how it works.

Comment: Do you know how to loop over a range denoted by two iterators?

Comment: You can reuse `iterator insert(const_iterator position, const Object& val)`, if you fix its broken return value.

Comment: @Caleth Yes I think i can.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm really sorry, but Can you show me a little bit how to implement?

Comment: Combine my comment with @Caleth's and think for a while. I'm sure you will come up with something.

Comment: @molbdnilo Okay, Thanks. So To make it sure, If i reuse  'iterator insert(const_iterator position, const Object& val)' Then I can get a answer. Right? I don't know how to utilize (InputIterator first, InputIterator last). I think I don't fully understand the role of those two things.

Comment: `reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);` invalidates all iterators, so you have to do `int index = position - objects;` before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular overload is a tricky thing, because it requires you to accept the most general kind of iterator, but people will expect better performance with other iterator types.

The naive way is to loop from `first` to `last`, `insert`ing each element.

```
template<typename InputIterator>
void insert(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
         position = insert(position, *first);
    }
}
```

However this may require multiple reallocations. You *must* do that with *InputIterator*s, because they don't necessarily support multiple passes, but it would be really useful to reserve enough space ahead of time.

You can have an extra overload that only applies to *ForwardIterator*s, which do support multiple passes, so you can know how much capacity is needed.

With C++20 this can be done by having overloads with constrained template types

```
template<std::input_iterator InputIterator>
void insert(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
         position = insert(position, *first);
    }
}

template<std::forward_iterator ForwardIterator>
void insert(const_iterator position, ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last) {
    auto requiredCapacity = theSize + std::distance(first, last);
    if (requiredCapacity > theCapacity) {
        auto index = std::distance(objects, position);
        reserve(requiredCapacity);
        position = objects + index;
    }
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
         position = insert(position, *first);
    }
}
```

Prior to C++20 you can have the public `insert` dispatch to one of two private implementations

```
template<typename InputIterator>
void insert(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    insert_impl(position, first, last, std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category{});
}

template<typename InputIterator>
void insert_impl(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last, std::input_iterator_tag) {
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
         position = insert(position, *first);
    }
}

template<typename ForwardIterator>
void insert_impl(const_iterator position, ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, std::forward_iterator_tag) {
    auto requiredCapacity = theSize + std::distance(first, last);
    if (requiredCapacity > theCapacity) {
        auto index = std::distance(objects, position);
        reserve(requiredCapacity);
        position = objects + index;
    }
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
         position = insert(position, *first);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I changed my code according to your advice.  But I can find garbage value and I don't know what is problem. Can you check my code? and according your code, Your code starts from first, but since my insert starts to copy from last, I changed it to explore from the last.

Comment: ```                                                                                                                         template <class InputIterator>
    iterator insert(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
    {
        int index = position - objects;
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
        {
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        }/*for (InputIterator it = last - 1; it == first; --it)
        {
            position=insert(position, *it);
        }*/
        
        theSize += index;
        return objects;
        }```

Comment: @Basicthings you aren't reserving the right capacity, and you are increasing the size twice